# 404 page not found after refreshing my react app in firebase hosting

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, firebase-hosting

My .json file of the project. With added 'rewrites' and 'hosting' json body

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  },
  "rewrites": [ {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
   } ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your directory structure? Does the build folder have a index.html file? Have you tried accessing the website from other device (or incognito mode)? Older version may have cached.

Comment: https://ibb.co/7KQSZMJ check this. Yes, I do hae a index.html file